SQL Server Query View / Performance Issues
I'm dealing with performance issues with a 3rd-party view that's pulling from our production db. Troubleshooting is currently being directed at the hardware of our SQL Server box. Just to give you an idea of our production database's size, the largest table is around 32mil records. There are no major performance issues within our production environment itself.
I'm concerned that the view itself is the issue; that we may end up bending over backwards on hardware overhauls (adding more SSDs, indexing, and potentially even partitioning production tables) for nothing. I only have a few years' experience with SQL, so I wanted someone with a more trained eye to see if anything jumps out as being bad practice in this view?
A simple select top 10 * from new_view statement takes over 40 seconds to run. I'm pasting a redacted version of the query below, just to show structure.
SELECT
        A.xxxxx,
        A.xxxxxxxxx,
        A.xxxxxx,
        E.xxxxxxx + '-' + substring(E.xxxxx, 1, LEN(E.xxxxx) - 1) + '-' + SUBSTRING(E.xxxxx, LEN(E.xxxxx), 1) [xxxxx],
        A.xxxxxxx,
        A.xxxxxxx,
        A.xxxxxx,
        A.xxxxxxxx,
        SUM(ISNULL(B.xxx_xxx, 0)),
        SUM(ISNULL(B.xxxxxx_xxxx, 0)),
        A.xxxxx,
        A.xxxxx,
        F.xxxxx,
        A.xxxxx,
        A.xxxxx,
        C.xxxxxxxxxxxx,
        C.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        C.xxxxxxxxxxx,
        A.xxxxxxxx,
        C.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        C.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        C.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        C.xxxxxxxxxx,
        D.xxxxxxxxx,
        E.xxxxxxxxxx,
        E.xxxxxxx,
        CASE
        WHEN
                EXISTS
                (
                        SELECT
                                1
                        FROM
                                Production.dbo.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx A1
                        WHERE
                                A1.xxxxxx = D .xxxxxx
                                AND A1.xxxxxx = 'xxxxxx')
        THEN
                CAST(1 AS bit)
        ELSE
                CAST(0 AS bit)
        END [xxxxxxxxx],
        CASE
        WHEN
                EXISTS
                (
                        SELECT
                                1
                        FROM
                                Production.dbo.xxxxxxxxx A1
                        WHERE
                                A1.[KEY]        = D.xx_xx
                                AND A1.xxxxxxx = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
                                AND A1.xx_xxxx IS NOT NULL)
        THEN
                CAST(1 AS bit)
        ELSE
                CAST(0 AS bit)
        END [xxxxxxxx],
        G.xxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        G.xxxxxxxxxxxx,
        G.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        H.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        I.xxxxxxxxx,
        J.xxxxxxxx,
        K.xxxxxxxxx,
        L.xxxxxxx,
        CASE
        WHEN
                A.xxxx = 'xxxx'
                AND A.xxxxxxx LIKE 'x%'
        THEN
                CAST(1 AS BIT)
        ELSE
                CAST(0 AS BIT)
        END [xxxxxxxx],
        CASE
        WHEN
                A.xxxxxxxx = 'xxxx'
                AND A.xxxxxxx LIKE 'x%'
        THEN
                CAST(1 AS BIT)
        ELSE
                CAST(0 AS BIT)
        END [xxxxxxxxx]
FROM
        Production.dbo.xxxxxxxx A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Production.dbo.xxxxxxxxx F
ON
        A.xxxxxxx = F.xx_xx
INNER JOIN
        Production.dbo.xxxxx B
ON
        A.xxID = B.xxID
OUTER APPLY
        (
                SELECT
                        TOP 1 A1.xxxxxxID,
                        A1.xxxxx,
                        B1.xxxxxxxxxxx,
                        A1.xxxxxxxxxx,
                        A1.xxxxxxxx,
                        A1.xxxxxxxx,
                        A1.xxxxxxxxx,
                        A1.xxxxxxxxxx,
                        A1.xxxxxxxxxxxx
                FROM
                        dbo.xxxxxxx A1
                INNER JOIN
                        dbo.xxxxxxxx B1
                ON
                        A1.xxxID = B1.xxxID
                WHERE
                        A1.xxxID = A.xxxID
                ORDER BY
                        A1.xxxxxx DESC) C
INNER JOIN
        Production.dbo.xxxxxxxxx D
ON
        A.xxxID = D .xxxxID
INNER JOIN
        Production.dbo.xxxxxxxxx E
ON
        D .xxxID  = E.xxxxID
AND     E.xxxx = 'Y'
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.xxxxxxxxxxxxx G
ON
        A.xxCD = G.xxCD
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
                SELECT
                        A1.xxxID,
                        STRING_AGG(A1.xxxxx, ',') [xxxxxxxxxxx]
                FROM
                        dbo.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx A1
                GROUP BY
                        A1.xxxxxxxxxID) H
ON
        G.xxxxxxxxxxID = H.xxxxxxxxxxxID
OUTER APPLY
        
        (
                SELECT
                        TOP 1 A1.xxxxID
                FROM
                        Production.dbo.xxxxxxx A1
                WHERE
                        A1.xxxxID = D.xxx_ID
                AND     A1.xxxxxx IN ('xxxxxxx')
                ORDER BY
                        A1.xxxxxx DESC) I
OUTER APPLY
        
        (
                SELECT
                        TOP 1 A1.xxxxxID
                FROM
                        Production.dbo.xxxxxxxxx A1
                WHERE
                        A1.xxxxID = D.xxxxID
                AND     A1.xxxxxx IN ('xxxxx')
                ORDER BY
                        A1.xxxxx DESC) J
OUTER APPLY
        
        (
                SELECT
                        TOP 1 A1.xxxxxxxx
                FROM
                        Production.dbo.xxxxxxxx A1
                WHERE
                        A1.xxxxID = D.xxxID
                AND     A1.xxxxx IN ('xxxxxx')
                ORDER BY
                        A1.xxxxxx DESC) K
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        
        Production.dbo.xxxxxxxx L
ON
        E.xxxID = L.xxxx_id
GROUP BY
        A.xxxxx,
        A.xxxxxxxxx,
        A.xxxxx,
        A.xxxxxxx,
        A.xxxxxxx,
        A.xxxxxxxxx,
        A.xxxxxxxxxx,
        A.xxxxx,
        A.xxxxxxx,
        F.xxxxxx,
        A.xxxxxxx,
        A.xxxxxx,
        C.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        C.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        A.xxxxxxxx,
        C.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        C.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        C.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        C.xxxxxxxxxxx,
        E.xxxxxxxxxx,
        E.xxxxxxxxx,
        D.xxxxxxxxx,
        D.xxxxxx,
        D.xxxxx,
        C.xxxxxxxxxxx,
        G.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        G.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        G.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        H.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        E.xxxxx,
        E.xxxxxxxx,
        I.xxxxxxxxx,
        J.xxxxxxxxx,
        K.xxxxxxxxx,
        L.xxxxxxx,
        A.xxxxxxxxx


Anonymized version (.pesession file) of the execution plan:
https://jkj7.com/files/exeplan_anonymized.pesession

Anonymized plans are a misery to look at, but you'll want to start by addressing these Eager Index Spools:

Looking at the query you provided, they are coming from the three OUTER APPLY subqueries.
You can find out more about fixing those in these posts, both by me:

How Eager Index Spool Operators Hurt Query Performance In SQL Server
Indexing SQL Server Queries For Performance: Fixing An Eager Index Spool

If you need further help, please provide an actual execution plan. Estimated plans leave much to be desired as far as details go.

Thank you for the guidance on the outer apply. I realize you're limited on details here, but zooming out a bit, would you agree this is a query-design issue and not a hardware/db-size one? [FYI, our hardware is running on flash-SSD's with avg. latency of .006ms, peak ~1ms.]

@JamesJohnson if you'd like that sort of assessment, I am available for consulting.

Subqueries in a column expression are often a source of performance issues. SQL Server generally can't (or won't try to) optimize those, so they get run in sequence, over and over again. I would try converting those CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 ...) THEN CAST(1 AS bit) ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) END statement to use an OUTER APPLY. This doesn't always work, but it's a quick and easy thing to do that sometimes has a big pay-off.
It should also be noted that the larger the GROUP BY clause is, the slower the query generally runs. If there's any logical way to group on a smaller set of predicates, possibly in an inner query before taking on everything else, that give you a performance boost too.
